# Functional equation polynomial problem: $x^2f(x-1)=(x-1)^2f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, functional-equations

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial such that $$x^2f(x-1)=(x-1)^2f(x)$$
> which one of the polynomials $(a)$ $x(x-1)$, $(b)$ $2016x$ or $(c)$ $2016x^2$ can $f(x)$ be?

How should one approach this? I cannot see any options to use other than trying to find some roots, but even that seems very hard here.

Comment: There's only three possibilities, so "bruteforce" is probably the fastest option I reckon. But I agree it's not very elegant

Comment: Maybe try out the three options? It shouldn’t be too hard.

Answer (score 5):

$\frac {f(x-1)}{(x-1)^2}= \frac{f(x)}{x^2}$
$ \\ \Rightarrow  \frac{f(x)}{x^2}= C \\
or \ f(x) = C{x^2}$

Comment: That is much simpler :). +1

Comment: Could you elaborate on how do we know that $\frac{f(x-1)}{(x-1)^2}$ equals some constant?

Comment: If we know the value of the function at some point then we can reduce the argument of the function till we dont get that value

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating 
$$x^2f(x-1)=(x-1)^2f(x)$$
at $x=0$ implies $f(0)=0$. Now by differentiating both sides of the equation we find
$$2xf(x-1)+x^2f'(x-1)=2(x-1)f(x)+(x-1)^2f'(x).$$
Again, plug $x=0$ to deduce $f'(0)=0$. Hence, the only possible candidate is $f(x)=2016x^2$.

Comment: Interesting idea to use the derivative!